# Suggestion : KB 2756920 causes several issues

Tags: search, user-profile-service

KB 2756920 causes several errors like Search scope may not function and user profile service may break causing your SharePoint site go down, so make sure your server did not update this article. I thought to inform you guys as a suggestion as it took me a three days to know why my SharePoint site got down unexpectedly.

Comment: I understand you are trying to help users who may have installed the update, but this is a Q and A site, so this doesn't fit the format I'm afraid (see the FAQ). Maybe you could re-phrase in the form of a question to Trevor's answer. If you do just flag for moderator attention and we can re-open. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See here: [Installing KB2756920 (MS13-004) on Windows Server 2008 R2 RTM breaks SharePoint 2010](http://sharepoint.nauplius.net/2013/01/installing-kb2756920-ms13-004-on-windows-server-2008-r2-rtm-breaks-sharepoint-2010/)

Two options:

1) (preferred) Install Server 2008 R2 SP1

2) Install KB2637518 and then the MS13-004 update

Comment: yes we need to install KB2637518 along with KB2756920 so that the server works normal.